# Dropdown Menu goes underneath image

Tags: html, css

Today I encountered a weird experience in my site [LiveGreen](http://livegreen.space/)

When I hover on the Menu Services, the dropdown goes underneath the image section below that. I tried every possible way like positioning and z-index ing and all kind, and googled a lot, am not bad with HTML and CSS still, it is testing me.

This theme is purchased, so cant post the code. you can check it from the website itself.

Please Help me.

Comment: i think you have some problem with loading resources via https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the z-index property on your `.main` class.

```
.main {
  z-index: 1; /* this is causing your problems */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly difficult to pull off because there are so few unique classes to key off of.  The root cause of the issue for you is that the element with a z-index that is higher than your menu applies that z-index higher up the DOM tree which makes it render on top.  The best I could come up with is to apply the following, provided that the `#aq-block-8801-5` block is always and will always be the nav menu container.

```
#aq-block-8801-5 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: No, That couldn't save me sorry, but thanks for your effort. It is solved anyways.

Comment: @CodeName44 Glad you're problem is resolved.  I'll leave this here just in case it's useful for someone else in the future.  IMI's solution is definitely better for your case, but in others it might be necessary to override z-index higher up the DOM, in which case this answer might still prove useful to someone.  Happy coding. :)